# Don't reload application when orientation changes

Tags: android

I simply need nothing to change when the screen is rotated. My app displays a random image when it first loads and rotating the device should *not* select another random image. 
How can I (simply) make this behavior stop?

Comment: It's also possible to lock (and possibly unlock) the screen orientation from code. Just call `Screen.lockOrientation(this)` from https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/Screen.java for this. It allows unlocking which the manifest does not.

Comment: @Escobar Ceaser What is the proper solution for this question.Even I have same requirement.

Comment: I would like to do this programmatically in code.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

There are generally three ways to do this:

1. As some of the answers suggested, you could distinguish the cases of your activity being created for the first time and being restored from `savedInstanceState`. This is done by overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and checking the parameter of `onCreate`.
2. You could lock the activity in one orientation by adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` (or `"landscape"`) to `<activity>` in your manifest.
3. You could tell the system that you meant to handle screen changes for yourself by specifying `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the `<activity>` tag. This way the activity will not be recreated, but will receive a callback instead (which you can ignore as it's not useful for you).

Personally I'd go with (3). Of course if locking the app to one of the orientations is fine with you, you can also go with (2).

Comment: So for #3 are you saying all I have to do is add that line to my manifest? Because it doesn't work.

Comment: ps... #2 doesnt work either. it just forces the app to display in a certain orientation. rotating the screen still reloads the activity.

Comment: #3 Please check on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: #3 was not working for me, I have added this:  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: @EscobarCeaser, For Android 3.2 and above, you need `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: for me, solution #3 worked perfectly. The activity is not recreated after device rotation. Thanks!

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` works for me. Thanks @Pacerier

Comment: please, update your answer case #3 with `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` value for API >=13, because a lot of people see your answer as main!

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" works for me

Comment: case #3 worked for me, But there is a problem with it when i m switching from portrait to landscape then screen is not fitting in device width. it is setting width size as per portrait's width.

Comment: #3 worked, haven't tested without setRetainInstance(true);

Comment: More info about android:configChanges: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: #3 worked for me along with  android:screenOrientation="nosensor"

Comment: what about `smallestScreenSize`?

Comment: Option #3 for me, is perfect!

Comment: It's working fine, But, Google does not recommend the most application in this approach. Please let me know the best way to achieve ???

Answer (score 219):

Xion's answer was close, but #3 (`android:configChanes="orientation"`) won't work unless the application has an API level of 12 or lower.

In API level 13 or above, the screen size changes when the orientation changes, so this still causes the activity to be destroyed and started when orientation changes.

Simply add the "screenSize" attribute like I did below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Now, when you change orientation (and screen size changes), the activity keeps its state and `onConfigurationChanged()` is called. This will keep whatever is on the screen (ie: webpage in a Webview) when the orientation changes.

Learned this from this site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Also, this is apparently a bad practice so read the link below about Handling Runtime Changes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thanks... its work after added "screenSize" with "orientation"

Comment: Works in Samsung Galaxy Nexus android 4.2.1 !
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: Amazing. Have been working through code for so many hours to solve an issue i had with activity reloading and a video starting from the beginning. And here was the solution ! ++++1

Comment: Bad practice? Pfft, real life people have deadlines and if it works, it works ;)

Comment: If this is a bad practice then why did it get so much upvotes ??

Comment: @SharpEdge Because people are lazy.

Comment: @Kernald, my comment was old, after working on fragments, now I can confirm that this indeed is bad practise!

Comment: @SharpEdge The explanation can still be usefull to someone else.

Comment: what about `smallestScreenSize`?

Comment: @corbin : Google does not recommend the most application in this approach. Please let me know the best way to achieve ???

Comment: @ManikandanK per my answer Android recommends hooking into lifecycle methods as a best practice. Hopefully the link above can help you. Good luck!

Comment: This very helpful

Answer (score 27):

You just have to go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and inside or in your activities labels, you have to type this line of code as someone up there said:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

So, you'll have something like this:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityMenu"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: its not loading my layout-land layout. :( didn't worked for me

Answer (score 16):

```
<activity android:name="com.example.abc" 
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

Just add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in activity tab of manifest file.

So, Activity won't restart when orientation change.

Comment: Its working. But when I am using separate layout for each orientation layout.xml and layout-land.xml. its applying landscape layout for both orientation. If I use "orientation" only , Its giving what I expect but reloading. Could you help on this ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe That's the issue when you're trying to cheat. You'll *have* to restart your activity to change layout. Go ahead and just use the real solution, which is using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()`.

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay and how am I suppose to do that?

Comment: @Weaboo the actual solution is linked in the question: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: @MarcPlano-Lesay I've separate layout for portrait and landscape mode, if I open my app in landscape or portrait mode it works fine but whenever I try to change orientation on run time it closes my app, however when I login to my app and then navigate to MainActivity and try to change orientation it reloads that activity and works fine. Now the question is why? Is there a logical error in my code? Idk, but I've tried debugging the app several times, and I can't find anything. Moreover I don't want to restart my activity, why can't we just adapt respective layout whenever configuration changes?

Answer (score 11):

It's my experience that it's actually better to just deal with the orientation changes properly instead of trying to shoehorn a non-default behavior.

You should save the image that's currently being displayed in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it properly when your application runs through `onCreate()` again.

Comment: #3 is a perfectly valid solution. It's the **exact** tool made to solve this exact problem. Why do you say that it's shoehorning?

Comment: @Pacerier Just read the docs. "Note: Using `android:configChanges` should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read *Handling Runtime Changes* for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change."

Comment: Could you post an example saving and restoring.

Answer (score 6):

This solution is by far the best working one. In your manifest file add

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:name="your activity name"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
  </activity
```

And in your activity class add the following code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //your code
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  //your code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In manifiest file add to each activity this. This will help

```
android:configChanges = "orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

Comment: screenLayout worked for me, prevented refresh when resizing app for splitscreen on android

Answer (score 4):

add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` for **all the app activities** tags in manifest.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

I mean, there is an activity tag, add this as another parameter. In case if you need portrait orientation, change landscape to portrait. Hope this helps.

Comment: im not looking to take away the ability to rotate the screen. i just dont want my app to reload... as i mentioned.

Comment: ps... this doesnt work anyway. it just forces the app to display in a certain orientation. rotating the screen still reloads the activity

Answer (score 2):

just use : `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Answer (score 2):

As Pacerier mentioned,

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Answer (score 2):

All above answers are not working for me. So, i have fixed by mentioning the `label` with `screenOrientation` like below. Now everything fine

```
<activity android:name=".activity.VideoWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://animeshrivastava.blogspot.in/2017/08/activity-lifecycle-oncreate-beating_3.html

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b)
{
        super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
    String str="Screen Change="+String.valueOf(screenChange)+"....";
        Toast.makeText(ctx,str+"You are changing orientation...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    screenChange=true;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prevent Activity to recreated
Most common solution to dealing with orientation changes by setting the android:configChanges flag on your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. Using this attribute your Activities won’t be recreated and all your views and data will still be there after orientation change.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

this is work for me

Answer (score 1):

Save the image details in your `onPause()` or `onStop()` and use it in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to restore the image.

EDIT:

More info on the actual process is detailed here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle as it is different in Honeycomb than previous Android versions.

Comment: actually you should do it in the onSaveInstanceState() method

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if the a best solution, but i describe it here:

First of all, you need certificate with you class Application of your app is in your manifest of this:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    ...
```

Second, in my class App i did like this:

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static boolean isOrientationChanged = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NotNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ||
                newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            isOrientationChanged = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Third, you need to set a flag to Orientation Change, in my case, I always set it when the previous activity within the app navigation is called, so only calling once when the later activity is created.

```
isOrientationChanged = false;
```

So every time I change the orientation of my screen in that context, I set it every time it changes this setting, it checks if there is a change in orientation, if so, it validates it based on the value of that flag.

Basically, I had to use it whenever I made an asynchronous retrofit request, which he called every moment that changed orientation, constantly crashing the application:

```
if (!isOrientationChanged) {
    presenter.retrieveAddress(this, idClient, TYPE_ADDRESS);
}
```

I don't know if it's the most elegant and beautiful solution, but at least here it's functional :)

Answer (score -2):

Add this code after the `onCreate` ,method in your activity containing the `WebView`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);    
}
```

Comment: How would this work? Aren't you just saying something explicitly to the runtime, what would otherwise be done by default?