# Layout Inflation SavedInstanceState after screen rotation

Tags: android

I am doing a very basic layout inflation of a XML layout into a linear layout container. The inflation is working however when I rotate the view that was inflated disappears (as expected) what I want to know is there a way to save the inflation or view group such as through on save instance state so that I do not need to inflate again since I read layout inflation is expensive!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: It says in the caution box that I should not pass views as they can leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about View inflations being expensive at orientation change! This is how Android works, on orientation change your Activity gets recreated. Period.

But if you really need to (you probably don't), it is possible to force an Activity to not get recreated, in short use android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest activity declaration. More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933583/forcing-android-to-not-redraw-activity-on-orientation-change).

Comment: thanks, i'll just re-inflate the view because its only just one view anyway.

Comment: Please don't use configChanges.  If you don't know whether you should or not, you should not.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html