# EditText changes color as the screen rotates

Tags: android

I have an EditText that takes the color of an xml.

`myr1.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.myr_ok);`

I know that when you rotate the screen activity is destroyed, and I managed to retrieve some data (values, status button) using onSaveInstanceState () but I can not find how to retrieve the color of the edit text (can be green or red) and keep .
Is it possible with onSaveInstanceState () or I have to use another way?

Comment: refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11704556/1278196)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getTextColors()` in `onSaveInstanceState` to retrieve the current color state list for the `TextView`.
Alternatively you could keep a variable remembering the resource ID of which text appearance style you last set, and save this in `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: Solved, I had to process the data type "Int".
Thanks Joseph,