# How to maintain the data even when the mode is changed from portrait to landscape and vice versa?

Tags: android, mode, data-loss

I have 25 `edittexts` and other views on my activity. I have created different `main.xml` files in `layout` and `layout-land`, so the respective **UI** will be displayed according to the **switched mode**(either **portrait** or **landscape**).

But After filling values in the `edittexts`, if I change from the **portrait** to **landscape**, the previous values are **lost**. So, my doubt is how to **get** the values from the `edittexts` and **restore** the values at their respective `edittexts` even after **changing** to other mode.

Of course I know when we **switch** modes, the activity is **recreated** which results the **data loss**. I have revised even `Handling Runtime changes` in the developer guide, but as a newbie I am unable to understand clearly like `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method to save data as it returns object, but in my app I need the numbers that are entered in the `edittexts` to be on their respective `edittexts` even after **switching**.

Have referred lot of questions like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes) etc., even on **stackoverflow**, but I am unable to find solution for my problem. Please suggest the solution for this.

Even I have another problem. I have a `dialog` which pops up when this `activity` is first started and I don't want this too to `popup` while **switching** modes. Please suggest the solution for these two. If anyone needs code snippet for more clarification, please let me know. I will edit my question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a less data you can save and get it using `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.. for details go through this link [Saving Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

But incase you have large data then I must say you should not allow for the orientation changes you can restrict it by adding below line in manifest file :

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Above line fixes orientation but in this case your `layout-land` will not work but you can handle or repositioned your view dynamically inside `onConfigurationChanged()` method

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        align_landscape(); // align your view dynamically here for landscape
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        align_portrait(); // align your view dynamically here for portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arfin. Thanks a lot for your response. Your explanation is very clear. But here I have large data. Adding my view dynamically is very complex. Becuase I have 25 edittexts and 10 buttons which make a custom keypad. Is it possible to get the solution in another way? Do you have any idea what is onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() meant for. It returns object but I need values.

Comment: I have used setContentView(R.layout.main); in the onConfigurationChanged() method. So the view is changed to the respective mode. The problem is I am able to retrieve the values but I am unable to set the values in the edittexts. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the edit text values when the orientation changes and then switch to the new layout and assign the saved values.

By specifying the following condition in the manifest, you can detect the orientation change.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in you onConfigurationChanged() method, store the values of the various fields and then you can change the orientation using the `setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation)` method which will update to your custom layout, then restore the values of your fields.

Comment: Thank you Gan. Will let you know if this works. What about Dialog reappearing problem?

Comment: could you elaborate on the pop-up dialog. Are you make a toast or is it generated by the system?

Comment: I just have a dialog before the main activity starts which asks the user some choices to select. But when I change the mode, even the dialog is also appearing every time.

Comment: When the orientation changes, the onCreate method gets called again, so the dialog is displayed. If you follow the idea that I have suggested you can avoid that.

Comment: Gan,I have used setContentView(R.layout.main); in the onConfigurationChanged() method. So the view is changed to the respective mode. The problem is I am able to retrieve the values but I am unable to set the values in the edittexts. Please reply.

Comment: use the setText() method of the EditText to assign the stored values.

Comment: Yes, I used, but didn't work. I found the reason for that. But unable to solve. Can you pls come to chat?