# Android video view

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to implement a video player using video view in android. Everything is working from functionality point of view. But there is a problem with full screen mode and orientation change. I want video view in such way that, In Landscape mode full screen video should be played and in portrait mode it should be positioned at center with Width as Fill_parent and Height as Wrap_content. So is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can create two diff layouts for two different orientations. Then you can dynamically assign the particular layout on orientation change. Like this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            //opening particular layout
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //checking whether orientation is portrait or landscape
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
            {

    setContentView(R.layout.main_portrait);
                }

else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
        {
setContentView(R.layout.main_land);
            }
```

Then you may design both the layouts differently according to your requirements.

Comment: After changing orientation it stops video and a black screen appear.

Comment: Actually your activity is getting refreshed on orientation change. To stop that please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5913370/1627599

Comment: Instead of doing setContentView in orientation change. Make a seprate folder with name as layout-land and paste the layout for landscape mode in that. it will automatically handle that.