# How to save a Handler in a Bundle in onSavedInstanceState()?

Tags: android, bundle, android-handler

I have to save `String`s and `Integer`s into a `Bundle` in `onSavedInstanceState()` so when the screen orientation changes it will continue where it left off in the other orientation.

Is is possible to store more complex objects like an instance of `Handler` into a `Bundle`? How can this be done?

Comment: Unless they implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, no they cannot.

Comment: @HoanNguyen what do you mean?

Comment: @MicroR My comment was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the documentation of [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to see which data type you can put into. Normally the object you can put into a `Bundle` must be primitive data types like `int`, `float`, `double`…; or must implement [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)/ [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) just extends `Object` so you cannot put it into a `Bundle`.

You can search for other solutions like:

- [Don't reload application when orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes)
- …