# onSizeChanged() calls onCreate() and onStart()? - Android

Tags: java, android

My app currently calls a method within the `onCreate()` method so that the game will start and animations will run once the view is created. However when i flip the screen to switch between portrait and landscape, this method is called again.

I've moved the calling line both to the `onStart()` method and even the methods class constructor.

this is the method that is being called:

```
public void startGame() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            runGame();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

There is a delay to allow everything to be constructed before it is run, otherwise it won't work.

Is there i way to stop `onSizeChanged()` affecting this method being called? Or is there a way i can call this method so that it starts when the activity is started (again so that `onSizeChanged()` cant affect it and that everything is initialized before its call).

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

which tells the system you'll take care of them yourself. [However, it's not recommended.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Or you can check savedInstanceState. If it is not null, that means a user changes the orientation (or the app are coming back from a configuration change). Maybe something likes this:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null)
    startGame();
else
    //handle a configuration change if necessary
```

Please see [Don't reload application when orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes)

Edit :

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
    startGame();
} else {
    //handle a configuration change if necessary
    int yourVar = savedInstanceState.getInt("something");
}
```

Comment: That works thank you :) is there a way i can save the state of another class (used by the View class, it creates a sequence and in the constructor it adds 3 integers to the sequence. so when i change the orientation it adds 3 again which i dont want).

Comment: @Waddas i'm not sure what you try to do but you can use onSaveInstanceState. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate

Comment: Sorry im not being clear. i have a class that does not implement View, is there a way i can save and restore its state so that chnging the orientation does not affect it?

Comment: From my understand, the state should be saved automatically. Anyway, you can override onSaveInstanceState() and add something likes this savedInstanceState.putInt("something", value); Then in onCreate retieve it using savedInstanceState.getInt("something");

Comment: please see my updated answer and also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate

Comment: If you are still not sure, could you ask another question with details (Your code) ? it looks like u'r having another problem

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help, you've solved my main problem which is a massive help :)

Comment: welcome. i'd be happy to help more but without your code, it's hard to show how to do things.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a static thread variable instead of handler?

e.g.

```
  private static Thread gameThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
              //if necessary: Thread.sleep(500);
              runGame();
        }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //rest of oncreate code here
        if(gameThread.isAlive() == false)
        {
              gameThread.start();
        }
  }
```

Comment: Not a good idea. When you initialize the `Runnable` object anonyomously, it will implicitly hold a reference to the parent class(In this case, an `Activity`), and that `Activity` will be leaked as long as the thread keeps running.