# Don't restart application on orientation change

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and have been making simple apps and in all of them have been making a method called void logic() that I have called at the end of my ViewDidLoad method. logic() contains all of the functionality that my app has. The issue with this is that whenever the screen changes orientation the ViewDidLoad method is re-called and then my app starts as if the application is being opened for the first time. Does anyone know how to do this? This is similar to this question [Don't reload application when orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes) however I do want ViewDidLoad to be re-called when the orientation is changed so that the view is recreated with the new orientation. However I don't want the application to be restarted. Thanks.

Comment: This link helped me the most: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/ and ...-part-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

or

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

And your activity manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".yourname"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```