# Forcing activity orientation recreates the activity twice

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

I'm trying to force all the Activities in my app to be either in portrait or landscape mode, exposing a setting to the user.

Basically in the onCreate() I request for the correct orientation somehow like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(SettingsHelper.getOrientation());
}
```

In fact what it does is that if we hold the device in **portrait** mode and the requested orientation is **landscape** then it simply creates an activity in portrait mode and then it recreates it in landscape. On high end devices this is acceptable since it is instantaneous, however on low end devices it is a disaster since between the creation and recreation there is a 5 second delay...

What I already tried:
- do it in the onResume not only in the onCreate
- define in the manifest android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
- define in the manifest android:screenOrientation="behind"
- define in the manifest android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
- define in the manifest android:configChanges="orientation"

Do you have any idea how to prevent the double creation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't reload application when orientation changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes)

Comment: @Szabolcs Becze: Because most people don't even understand the question and come up with the stock configChanges reply. :-) I don't think you found any solution because it's still here after some years... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828044/locking-android-orientation-based-on-preference/56830546#56830546

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your activity tag fo your AmdroidManifest.xml

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Example:

```
   <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried this one as well. The onCreate is invoked twice even if I add these flags.

Comment: Remove that setrequestedorientation method. if it does not work Share your code

Comment: Update: I Observed another thing which is interesting. Even though the activity is first displayed in portrait and then in landscape the onCreate and onResume is only invoked once.

Comment: There is nothing really what I can share... If I remove the setRequested Orientation than the orientation will not be changed. But I have to change the orientation.