# Locking Android orientation based on preference

Tags: android, screen-orientation

No, not a regurgitation of the old question, please, bear with me. I don't want to avoid activity recreation in general (no `android:configChanges` in manifest), I don't want to fix my orientation permanently (no `android:screenOrientation` in manifest) just because I'm lazy to implement instance saving.

I have an app with three possible settings the user can make: 1. automatically changing layout on orientation, as per normal, 2. fixed portrait, 3. fixed landscape. It makes sense in my case because the portrait and landscape displays show different functionality and the user *might* want to restrict to just one. Doesn't have to but has the possibility.

The app works just fine. I read the preference setting in `onCreate` and call `setRequestedOrientation` if I'm in one of the fixed modes. I let the system handle the orientation changes, I don't ask for handling the changes myself.

The only performance problem is that when, for instance, the app is started in the device's portrait position but fixed to landscape, `onCreate` will be called twice, once for the original startup, once for `setRequestedOrientation`. It works flawlessly, I handle it perfectly but there is a performance penalty, the activity appears with an obvious delay. (With `screenOrientation` fixed in the manifest, only for the purpose of testing, the startup looks much better, with only a single call to `onCreate`).

So, what I'm looking for is a kind of code equivalent of the manifest `screenOrientation` setting. I can't and don't want to specify it in the manifest but calling it from `onCreate` is already a bit late for performance.

Comment: try calling setRequestedOrientation before setContentView(), or even before         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Comment: No dice. I even tried to move it to `onStart` but no difference... Works just fine but with a visible lag compared to the manifest-fixed scenario. That one starts very nice.

Comment: onStart in called after onCreate, so it's normal there was no change.

Comment: Well, I didn't look it up this time, just tried. :-) But yes, true.

Comment: another possible solution, create a BaseActivity where you call setRequestedOrientation in onCreate, and make all activities inherit from it

Comment: No, not really, doesn't help. Always the same. Exaggerated when I run the app with the debugger attached but clearly visible in normal functioning, too. Basically, the screen rotates to landscape, then the contents start to appear. With the orientation fixed, the content already appears during the rotation. Just doesn't feel responsive enough and the vexing part is that the system can do it all right... :-)

Comment: I had some hopes with a `NoDisplay`-themed extra launch activity starting different aliases of the main activity but no. Screen orientation cannot be overridden in an alias, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read users preference in **Application Class**, and in the onCreate setContentView on the basis of that value.

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
  public void onCreate(){
   // get user preference here in a global variable
   }
}
```

Set this as application class in Manifest.

Then in your activities onCreate, use this value to determine layout before setContentView().

Comment: Sorry, that's not the solution. I can read the preference before `setContentView` either in the application or the activity, there's no problem with that. The problem is that whatever I do in `onCreate` is already too late. Even if before calling `setContentView`, even if before calling `super.onCreate`, I'm already *inside* onCreate, so changing the orientation will call `onCreate` a second time. The docs say so in no uncertain terms and also state that if I could call `setRequestedOrientation` *before* the activity is created, it would apply for the next creation. Only that I can't...

Comment: onResume() goes before onCreate, did you tried there?

Comment: Well, Google doesn't seem to agree with you: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my mistake...My memory failed me, didn't checked the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" />
```

This ***configChanges*** line on the manifest file should avoid the re-calling to the onCreate method :)

Comment: No, I did not. I specifically stated in the question that I'm not after the usual cheap alternatives that remove the burden of handling the orientation changes from the system. I want to retain the full functionality offered by Android, including responding to orientation changes *while the app runs*, I only want to avoid that single performance issue at start.

Comment: I think that you will keep all the functionality on, just is saving the state when changes the orientation etc. so you don't have to manage all that events and don't need to worry about double calling to onCreate().

Comment: No. If I do so, I lose all functionality, the layouts will no longer adapt to the rotation of the device, Android will no longer automatically use my various resources in xxx, xxx-port and xxx-land folders, and so on. I need all that functionality, I don't want to cripple any of it (and this is why the documentation very seriously warns against using configChanges). What I would need (but, as it seems, there simply is no way to achieve it) is to optimize *one single startup event* and I'm not willing to sacrifice everything else just because of it.