# How to handle activity orientation change to dont recreate the activity?

Tags: java, android

I start an activity with startActivityForResult() but after the orientatikn changed and i return to the onActivityResult() method the requestCode not the same. I would like to use different layout if the screen orientation is in landscape mode.
I tried in the manifest the configuration with orientation and screenSize params, but if i use this the layout not changed to the landscape layout.
I started the activity with requestCode=0 but after the orientation changed i see that the requestCode = 66357 or something.

Comment: Are u using a fragment or a dialog?

Comment: Just a simple Activity.

Comment: When the orientation is changed, the activity is recreated. No longer the same! So, you need pass the requestCode on onPause() or on Destroy() via intent.

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity.

In your AndriodMainfest.xml define configChanges

```
<activity android:name=".ResultActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then in your ResultActivity.java(that you call to get result) define onConfigurationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

official [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create two types of the layout folders. "layout-land" and "layout-port". put the required xml in both the directory with same name.

Comment: I did it, but i didnt see that the land layout was selected.

Comment: Declaring config changes in manifest is not required.you can keep one as default "layout" and other "layout-land".

Comment: But after the orientation changed and finish the activity it will return to the onActivityResult() method with a different requestCode. How should i handle this?

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

A)Set your app to not rotate.

B)Or accept that the world is not perfect yet and modify your app to handle configuration change

Comment: Provide code not suggestion , and this is more of a comment