# Android percent screen width in RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

How would I get a RecyclerView's item height to be, say, 30% of the screen's height?

I can't simply use a ConstraintLayout or a PercentFrameLayout/PercentRelativeLayout, since those position child layouts relative to parent layouts, whose size might not match the screens.

Preferably, I'd like to do this in pure XML (and not have to use any Runnables to get the screen height dynamically).

**EDIT**

To clarify, since a lot of solutions suggest restraining the height of the RecyclerView, that's not the intent. The RecyclerView should still populate the screen. Here's what I'm talking about, using the screen width (instead of height):

[image]

The idea is to **get the card's width to be 33% the screen's width**, while keeping the RecyclerView's width unaltered as it scrolls past the screen horizontally.

Comment: Let me know if this explanation is unclear: I know you can set percentages according to the size of the enclosing PercentLayout or ConstraintLayout. However, since I'm dealing with items in a RecyclerView, the enclosing layout is neither.

Comment: I think You should read this [don't-reload-application-when-orientation-changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes)

Comment: What does that question have to do with this one?

Answer (score 127):

You can override one of the `LayoutManager` methods used by your `RecyclerView` to force specific size:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this){
    @Override
    public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
        // force height of viewHolder here, this will override layout_height from xml
        lp.height = getHeight() / 3;
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is assuming your `RecyclerView` fits the screen.

If you want more complex solution (custom layout manager with per-item control & percent inflation straight from from XML) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794428/9241978).

Comment: This solution is better than passing context in recyclerview to calculating the width or height with widnowManager.

Comment: More complete example with margins applied and centering the first/last element: https://gist.github.com/crysxd/44342ace6c20c469f24f6a90168e2de8

Comment: Simple and sweet, No UI fluctutations

Comment: If someone wants a `HORIZONTAL` `RecyclerView` use `new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)` where 3rd param is `boolean reverseLayout`

Answer (score 52):

There is no way to do this in XML that I'm aware of. However, you can do it in Java (without any `Runnable`s etc) by setting your `ViewHolder`'s `itemView`'s `LayoutParams` before returning the `ViewHolder` in your adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` method:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (int) (parent.getHeight() * 0.3);
    itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: how do i apply this for my width? I want to show 80% of a card on the screen and right next to it, i want to show the next card content peeking through. is there a way to do this with recycler view , as a carousel?

Comment: did you think that `parent.getHeight()` or `parent.getWidth()` can return `0`, especially if you put your `RecyclerView` inside `ConstraintLayout`: `<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>`

Comment: Declaring `layout_width="0dp"`, and then setting constraints to define the width, will result in a `getWidth()` of a real value, and not 0.

Comment: @BenP. just try it yourself, it will be a real value of course but not than soon, when `onCreateViewHolder` is called it will be 0, but then a little bit later it will be a real value

Comment: This is not a valid answer. This is not applicable for horizontal scrolling behaviour. It decreases the view width

Comment: @user924 Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Display metrices

Define display metrices in constructor, or use any other static method initialization.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Now you can use it in **onCreateViewHolder()**

```
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

//setting the height programmatically
itemView.getLayoutParams().height = metrics.heightPixels/3;
itemView.requestLayout();
```

Or You can use in **onBindViewHolder()** on parent layout of layout.

Answer (score 4):

> You can not set percent height of item by XML only. Reason being it is
>   an item which will be inflated at run-time, it is not a activity like
>   layout. Which you write in your XML.

So now i tell you two ways to achieve percent / weight

**1st Preferred way** is to override height in `onCreateViewHolder()` method inside your `Adapter`

```
private int height = 0; // declared height globally in Adapter class to reuse it.

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    if (height == 0)
        height = (int) (parent.getMeasuredHeight() * .3);
    itemView.setMinimumHeight(height);
    return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

**2nd Hack is** to use [**SDP**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) library.

Use height of item in XML in `sdp` say `_160sdp`. It will not give you exact results of 30%. But it can adjust according to screen.

Comment: No, it is a little logic been added in thousands of UI processes.

Comment: If you still mention that we are getting `measuredHeight` many times, then you can hold first one in a global variable. Then reuse it.

Comment: The Edit you suggested does not make a difference if you don't check null and reuse it. I will edit it.

Comment: @salman already improved, and there was also one another fix for `parent.getContext()`.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by doing the following inside of my custom RecyclerView Item layout:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    val newMeasuredWidth =
        (MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * WIDTH_ADJUSTMENT_RATIO).toInt()
    super.onMeasure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(newMeasuredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        heightMeasureSpec
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int devicewidth = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.8);
    view.getLayoutParams().width = devicewidth;
    return new YourAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Just one time

```
inner class MyFeatureProductViewHolder(val v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    val tvName = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
    val tvPrice = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPrice)
    val tvItemUploadTime = v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvItemUploadTime)
    val ivItem = v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivItem)

    init {
        v.layoutParams.width =  itemView.measuredWidth - 20
        v.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the exact percentage, you can achieve the desired view by setting the `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` and also setting the `android:clipToPadding` to `false`.
This also makes first and last item align in center.

Answer (score -2):

Well I just tried to fix the issue you're having. I played with few things. Steps as follows:

1. MainActivity View Where RecyclerView has height of exactly 30% of screen.
   [image]
2. Recycler View Items Height and Width must be match_parent.
   [image]

**What's happening there?**

1. `recyclerHolder` has exactly 30% height of screen height there is no doubt.
2. Inside `recyclerHolder` we've `RecyclerView` which takes all those 30% height of parent and takes full width.
3. `ListItem Layout` takes full height and width of parent, where parent is `RecyclerView` which has exactly 30% height of screen.

I tried this and works perfectly. There you can find 2 empty views just to test if those fits perfectly on top and bottom, the result yes it does. put whatever inside list item it's gonna take 30% of screen height.