# Recycler view (horizontal) with two items 50% of the parent width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to make sure that in a recycler view (**horizontal** orientation and `LinearLayoutManager` set) that if I have 2 items to display they both get 50% of the parent layout. So both fit in the screen.
I have tried 2 approaches but neither works properly.
Approach 1:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item_view, parent, false)
        itemView.post(
            object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    itemView.layoutParams.width = (parent.width * 0.5).toInt()
                }

            }

        )
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
 }
```

This does not work unless I first scroll and then only the first item has its width adapted.

Approach 2:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list_item_view, parent, false)
       itemView.layoutParams.width = getScreenWidthFromUtils(context).x_width - MAGIC_NUMBER_WHICH_TAKES_PADDING_INTO_ACCOUNT)* 0.5).toInt()
       return ViewHolder(itemView)
 }
```

Approach 2 kind of works but obviously it can't be the solution as I doubt it has to be this complicated to achieve this.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android percent screen width in RecyclerView item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201482/android-percent-screen-width-in-recyclerview-item)

Comment: Why don't you use a `GridLayoutManager` instead of a `LinearLayoutManager` ?

Comment: @Biscuit: How would that help? I can switch if that solves it

Answer (score 0):

The `GridLayoutManager` will take care of giving your item the optimal size and space for the number of column you specify. In your case you want to have 2 items per row so your code should look like :

```kotlin
val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Comment: I'm using it horizontally as well. ```recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));``` but it gives me two rows instead of one. Any idea why?

Comment: You should look at what are GridLayoutManager and LinearLayoutManager

Comment: Using a GridLayoutManager is the wrong approach. This solution can't possibly work. The span count in a GridLayoutManager represents the number of columns/rows orthogonal to the scroll direction. So a GridLayoutManager with a spanCount of 2 gives you two **columns** in a **vertical** RecyclerView, but two **rows** in a **horizontal** RecyclerView. That's intended behaviour.