# RecyclerView Item Decoration - Why are margins being added to the bottom of my viewholders?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, item-decoration

I'm trying to add `Right` and `Left` margins to my `RecyclerView` on the `first` and `last` item with `Item Decorations`.

The right and left margins are being successfully added to the first and last, however the ones in the middle have margins on the bottom and I have NO IDEA where they are coming from.

[image]

**ItemDecoration:**

```
public class MapItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int spacing;

    public MapItemDecoration(int spacing) {
        this.spacing = spacing;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, @NonNull View view,
                               @NonNull RecyclerView parent,
                               @NonNull RecyclerView.State state
    ) {
        final int position = parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
        final int itemCount = state.getItemCount();

        
        if (position == 0) {
            //Adds margins on first item on the right side
            outRect.set(0, 0, spacing, 0);
        } else if (itemCount > 0 && position == itemCount - 1) {
            //Adds margins to the last item on the left side
            outRect.set(spacing, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            //Margins between first and last item on both right and left side.
            outRect.set(spacing, 0, spacing, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**ViewHolder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
adapter = new MapAdapter(listLocations, this);
int spacing = SpacingUtils.convertIntToDP(this, 32);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MapItemDecoration(spacing));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(
     this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false
));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly? Why are margins being added to the bottom of my `viewholders` even though I have the value set as `0` inside my ItemDecorations?

**Edit
:____________________________________________________**

I tried setting a specified `dp` width on the `ImageView` inside the `Viewholder`

**New ViewHolder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

This seems to remove the bottom margins. But I need the ImageView to be using the attributes

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
```

so my viewholder is scaled accordingly to the screensize. Is there another solution without setting the imageview as a specified width? Or maybe there is a way I could do it with percentage in the parent constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the margins from appearing on the bottom:

Removing the attributes

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
```

on my ImageView and setting it as

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And since I still wanted a square ImageView and a viewholder that was sized based on the screensize, I programmatically sized it inside my `onCreateViewHolder`

Thanks to this answer by Ben P. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51202132/11110509

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder_map, parent, false);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = itemView.getLayoutParams();
        int width = (int) (parent.getWidth() * 0.4);
        layoutParams.width = width;
        layoutParams.height = width;
        itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

And the ViewHolder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This way I still get the square imageview, and also scaled viewholder size based on the device.